# What is the probability that you a fair die lands on 1 or 2, given that you rolled a number strictly less than 4?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

What is the probability that you a fair die lands on 1 or 2, given that you rolled a number strictly less than 4?

While the solution give as 2/3. but I can't get the understanding right.

here is my thinking: P( 1or2 | l4 ) = P( l4 | 1or2 )P(1or2)/P(l4) but when i plug in P(1or2) =1/3 and P(l4)=2/3 and P(l4|1or2) = 1.( pretty sure this one doesn't look right) . Can get right. as 2/3 as the given solution. Anyone please give me a hand. Thank you in advance.

Comment: P(l4) is $\frac{1}{2}$, not $\frac{2}{3}$.  Here we are saying *strictly less* than four, in other words we rolled a $1$ a $2$ or a $3$.  This is different than rolling a number *less than or equal* to four.  This gives $(1/3) / (1/2)$ which simplifies to be $\frac{2}{3}$, as expected.

Comment: As an aside, there is no reason to have used Bayes' theorem here.  Just use $Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$.  There is no reason to have used $P(B\mid A)$ in this problem.

Comment: Even if the OP does use Bayes' theorem, $P(\text{less than 4}|\text{1 or 2}) = 1$ is obvious. If you know you rolled a 1 or a 2, you also rolled a value strictly less than 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in saying P(l4) is $\frac{2}{3}$.  Notice, that of the six equally likely sides to a standard die, exactly *three* of those sides are strictly less than $4$, and so the probability of having rolled a number strictly less than for is $\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$, not $\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$.  Having rolled a $4$ does not count as having rolled a number strictly less than $4$.

In making this correction, we get as an answer $\dfrac{~\frac{1}{3}~}{\frac{1}{2}}=\dfrac{2}{3}$ as expected.